# how to make the card draggable to other column using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, draggable

i made this using html, css and javascript (with a lot of help from ai)

as you can see it wont get dragged to the other columns, how do i fix this? i want to be able to make the cards to either be dragged to in progress or done or vice versa. but it wont be dragged over to the columns.... im stuck

```js
const addBox = document.querySelector(".addBox");
const popupBox = document.querySelector(".popup-box");
const closeIcon = popupBox.querySelector("header i");
const titleTag = popupBox.querySelector("input");
const descTag = popupBox.querySelector("textarea");
const addBtn = popupBox.querySelector("button");
const kanbanColumns = document.querySelectorAll(".kanban-column");
let selectedTag = "Personal"; // Default selected tag
let selectedTagColor = "#7875A9"; // Default tag color

const tagColors = {
  Personal: "#7875A9",
  Work: "#7DA9D6",
  School: "#FF8E8E",
  Coding: "#7BC683",
};

function loadTasksFromLocalStorage() {
  // Clear the Kanban board
  kanbanColumns.forEach((column) => {
    column.querySelector(".kanban-cards").innerHTML = "";
  });

  // Load tasks from local storage
  const storedTasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks") || "[]");

  // Populate the Kanban board with stored tasks
  storedTasks.forEach((task) => {
    createKanbanCard(task.title, task.description, task.tag, task.tagColor);
  });

  // Update your 'notes' array with the loaded tasks
  notes.length = 0; // Clear the notes array
  notes.push(...storedTasks);
}

// Call the function to load tasks when the page loads
window.addEventListener("load", loadTasksFromLocalStorage);

const notes = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("tasks") || "[]");

addBox.addEventListener("click", () => {
  popupBox.classList.add("show");
});

closeIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
  popupBox.classList.remove("show");
});

function createKanbanCard(title, description, tag, tagColor) {
  const card = document.createElement("div");
  card.classList.add("kanban-card");
  card.classList.add(`tag-${tag}`);
  card.draggable = true;
  card.dataset.tag = tag; // Store the tag information as a data attribute
  card.dataset.id = generateUniqueId();

  const cardTemplate = `
    <h4>${title}</h4>
    <p>${description}</p>
    <div class="kanban-card-tag" style="background-color: ${tagColor}">${tag}</div>
  `;

  card.innerHTML = cardTemplate;

  // Append the card to the appropriate column
  const targetColumn = Array.from(kanbanColumns).find(
    (column) => column.querySelector("h5").textContent.trim() === tag
  );

  if (targetColumn) {
    targetColumn.querySelector(".kanban-cards").appendChild(card);
  } else {
    // If the target column doesn't exist, default to the "To Do" column
    const todoColumn = kanbanColumns[0]; // First column is "To Do"
    todoColumn.querySelector(".kanban-cards").appendChild(card);
  }
}

addBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let noteTitle = titleTag.value;
  let noteDesc = descTag.value;

  if (selectedTag && (noteTitle || noteDesc)) {
    // Create a new Kanban card dynamically
    createKanbanCard(noteTitle, noteDesc, selectedTag, selectedTagColor);

    // Add the task to your notes array
    const newTask = {
      id: generateUniqueId(),
      title: noteTitle,
      description: noteDesc,
      tag: selectedTag,
      tagColor: selectedTagColor,
    };
    notes.push(newTask);

    // Save tasks to local storage
    localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(notes));

    // Clear the input fields
    titleTag.value = "";
    descTag.value = "";

    // Close the popup
    closeIcon.click();
  } else {
    alert("Please select a tag and fill in the title or description.");
  }
});

// Add a dragstart event listener to all Kanban cards
const kanbanCards = document.querySelectorAll(".kanban-card");
kanbanCards.forEach((card) => {
  card.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
    draggedCard = card; // Set the draggedCard variable
  });
});

// Add a dragover event listener to all Kanban columns
kanbanColumns.forEach((column) => {
  column.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    column.classList.add("hover");
  });

  column.addEventListener("dragleave", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    column.classList.remove("hover");
  });
});

// Add a drop event listener to all Kanban columns
kanbanColumns.forEach((column) => {
  column.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (draggedCard) {
      // Move the card to the new column
      column.querySelector(".kanban-cards").appendChild(draggedCard);

      // Update the card's status
      const newStatus = column.querySelector("h5").textContent.trim();
      const cardId = draggedCard.getAttribute("data-id");
      const updatedTask = notes.find((task) => task.id === cardId);
      if (updatedTask) {
        updatedTask.tag = newStatus;
        // Update the task's status in your data storage
        localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(notes));
      }

      // Reset the draggedCard variable
      draggedCard = null;
    }
  });
});

// Generate a unique ID for each card
function generateUniqueId() {
  return Date.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
}

// Event listener for radio buttons to update the selected tag
const tagRadioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="radio"]');

tagRadioButtons.forEach((radio) => {
  radio.addEventListener("click", () => {
    selectedTag = radio.nextElementSibling.textContent.trim();
    selectedTagColor = tagColors[selectedTag];
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;400;500;600&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  background: #f8f0ff;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 1.7rem;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  background: white;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.sidebar:hover {
  width: 240px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu {
  height: 88%;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  bottom: 1rem;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.logo {
  height: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #69665C;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.logoimg {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.logo h2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.dash:hover,
.dash {
  background-color: #FFF9DE;
}

.personal:hover,
#personal:active {
  background-color: #D2CEFF;
}

.work:hover,
.work:active {
  background-color: #D1E5F7;
}

.school:hover,
.school:active {
  background-color: #FFCECE;
}

.coding:hover,
.coding:active {
  background-color: #DAF2D6;
}

.logout:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

.logout:hover span {
  color: white;
}

.menu a {
  color: #69665C;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.menu a span {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu a i {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.fas.fa-user {
  color: #FFB843;
}

.fas.fa-clipboard {
  color: #7875A9;
}

.fas.fa-folder-open {
  color: #7DA9D6;
}

.fas.fa-book {
  color: #FF8E8E;
}

.fas.fa-laptop-code {
  color: #7BC683;
}

.fa-solid.fa-arrow-right-from-bracket {
  color: red;
}

.logout {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


/* MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */


/* MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */


/* MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */

.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #69665C;
}

.header-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 2rem;
}

.header-wrapper img {
  max-width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* /////MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */


/* MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */


/* MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */


/*yung notes*/


/* Add this CSS for the to-do cards */

.todo-card {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.todo-card-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 280px;
}

.todo-card-footer {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.todo-card-header h3 {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 260px;
}

.delete-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}

.fas.fa-trash {
  color: red;
}

.todo-text {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/* POP UP PAG INADD */

.popup-box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  z-index: 999;
  color: #69665C;
}

.popup-box .popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  justify-content: center;
}

.popup-box,
.popup-box .popup {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.popup-box.show,
.popup-box.show .popup {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.popup .content {
  background: lavender;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.popup .content header {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #69665C;
}

.content header p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.content header i {
  color: #69665C;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.content header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.content form {
  margin: 15px 25px 20px;
}

.content form .row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

form .row label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.content form :where(input,
textarea,
select) {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.content form textarea {
  height: 150px;
  resize: none;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}

.content form button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  background: #5D5A8C;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* ADD TASK */

.addBox {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  background: #7875A9;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.addBox:hover {
  background: #5D5A8C;
}

.addBox:active {
  transform: scale(1.01);
}

.add i {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.add p {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}


/* ADD TASK TAPOS */


/* tags */

.btn-radio {
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-radio input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.btn-radio input[type="radio"]+label span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.btn-radio input[type="radio"]:checked+label span {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-radio i {
  padding-right: 5px;
}


/* Kanban Board */

.kanban-board {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.kanban-column {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.kanban-column h5 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #69665C;
  color: #69665C;
}

.kanban-cards {
  min-height: 500px;
  /* Adjust the minimum height as needed */
}


/* Kanban Card */

.kanban-card {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.kanban-card h4 {
  font-size: .9rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.kanban-card p {
  font-size: .8rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.kanban-card-tag {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  font-size: .8rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


/* Define different styles for different card tags */

.kanban-card.tag-Personal {
  border-left: 3px solid #7875A9;
}

.kanban-card.tag-Work {
  border-left: 3px solid #7DA9D6;
}

.kanban-card.tag-School {
  border-left: 3px solid #FF8E8E;
}

.kanban-card.tag-Coding {
  border-left: 3px solid #7BC683;
}


/* Card Dragging Styles */

.kanban-card.is-dragging {
  opacity: 0.5;
}


/* Card Placeholder Styles */

.kanban-card-placeholder {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 150px;
  /* Adjust the height as needed */
  border: 1px dashed #333;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome Cdn Link -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04558dcba4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- POP UP PAG DRINAG -->
<div class="popup-box">
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="content">
      <header>
        <p>New Task</p>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
      </header>
      <form action="#">
        <div class="row title">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input id="title" placeholder="Enter your to-do here">
        </div>
        <div class="row description">
          <label for="desc">Description</label>
          <textarea id="desc" placeholder="Provide additional details..."></textarea>
        </div>



        <div class="row dropdown">
          <label>Tags</label>

          <div class="btn-radio" id="radio">
            <input type="radio" id="radio01" name="radio" />
            <label for="radio01"><span><i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i>Personal</span></label>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-radio">
            <input type="radio" id="radio02" name="radio" />
            <label for="radio02"><span><i class="fas fa-folder-open"></i>Work</span></label>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-radio">
            <input type="radio" id="radio03" name="radio" />
            <label for="radio03"><span><i class="fas fa-book"></i>School</span></label>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-radio">
            <input type="radio" id="radio04" name="radio" />
            <label for="radio04"><span><i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>Coding</span></label>
          </div>

        </div>
        <button>Add Task</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- DONE DRAG -->




<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="logo">
    <h2><img src="doit.png" class="logoimg"><span>DoIt!</span></h2>
  </div>

  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="dash">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        <span>Home</span>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="personal" id="personal" draggable="true">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i>
        <span>Personal</span>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="work">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-folder-open"></i>
        <span>Work</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="school">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
        <span>School</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="coding">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
        <span>Coding</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="logout">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i>
        <span>Log out</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- main sa right -->
<div class="main">
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="header-title">
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
    <img src="rimuru.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <!-- BUTTON PARA SA ADD -->
  <div class="addBox">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
    <p>Add Task</p>
  </div>

  <div class="kanban-board">
    <!-- To Do Column -->
    <div class="kanban-column">
      <h5>To do</h5>

      <div class="kanban-cards" id="todo-cards"></div>

    </div>

    <!-- In Progress Column -->
    <div class="kanban-column in-progress">
      <h5>In progress</h5>
      <div class="kanban-cards" id="inprogress-cards"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Completed Column -->
    <div class="kanban-column">
      <h5>Completed</h5>
      <div class="kanban-cards" id="completed-cards"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i used chatgpt and bard but nothing still happens

Comment: your code is not currently producing any card

Comment: when you add task, it does make a card

Comment: @GrafiCode , here is a fiddle of the code that let you add cards (SO doesn't allow locale storage from a snippet)  https://jsfiddle.net/bLr4zq8w/

Comment: @G-Cyrillus same behaviour on jsfiddle, I ended up removing references to localStorage to make the snippet work.

Comment: @GrafiCode, okay, funny it worked for me, probably the browser or a config i missed ;)

Answer (score 0):

(Removed all localStorage functions to make the snippet work in SO sandbox)

Problem 1 was `draggedCard` variable giving `undefined` (the way you declared it made its scope local). I declared `let draggedCard` on top of your code to widen its scope to the whole script.

Problem 2 was the way you were adding the dragstart event to your cards, below this comment `// Add a dragstart event listener to all Kanban cards`. Your cards are added to the DOM dynamically, and you were binding the event listener on document ready (when no card is present yet). I moved the binding inside the function `createKanbanCard`, where you actually create and add the card to the DOM.

P.S. Die chatGPT, DIE!!!

```js
const addBox = document.querySelector(".addBox");
const popupBox = document.querySelector(".popup-box");
const closeIcon = popupBox.querySelector("header i");
const titleTag = popupBox.querySelector("input");
const descTag = popupBox.querySelector("textarea");
const addBtn = popupBox.querySelector("button");
const kanbanColumns = document.querySelectorAll(".kanban-column");
let selectedTag = "Personal"; // Default selected tag
let selectedTagColor = "#7875A9"; // Default tag color
let draggedCard

const tagColors = {
  Personal: "#7875A9",
  Work: "#7DA9D6",
  School: "#FF8E8E",
  Coding: "#7BC683",
};


// Call the function to load tasks when the page loads

const notes = [];

addBox.addEventListener("click", () => {
  popupBox.classList.add("show");
});

closeIcon.addEventListener("click", () => {
  popupBox.classList.remove("show");
});

function createKanbanCard(title, description, tag, tagColor) {
  const card = document.createElement("div");
  card.classList.add("kanban-card");
  card.classList.add(`tag-${tag}`);
  card.draggable = true;
  card.dataset.tag = tag; // Store the tag information as a data attribute
  card.dataset.id = generateUniqueId();
  card.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
    draggedCard = card; // Set the draggedCard variable
  });

  const cardTemplate = `
    <h4>${title}</h4>
    <p>${description}</p>
    <div class="kanban-card-tag" style="background-color: ${tagColor}">${tag}</div>
  `;

  card.innerHTML = cardTemplate;

  // Append the card to the appropriate column
  const targetColumn = Array.from(kanbanColumns).find(
    (column) => column.querySelector("h5").textContent.trim() === tag
  );

  if (targetColumn) {
    targetColumn.querySelector(".kanban-cards").appendChild(card);
  } else {
    // If the target column doesn't exist, default to the "To Do" column
    const todoColumn = kanbanColumns[0]; // First column is "To Do"
    todoColumn.querySelector(".kanban-cards").appendChild(card);
  }
}

addBtn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let noteTitle = titleTag.value;
  let noteDesc = descTag.value;

  if (selectedTag && (noteTitle || noteDesc)) {
    // Create a new Kanban card dynamically
    createKanbanCard(noteTitle, noteDesc, selectedTag, selectedTagColor);

    // Add the task to your notes array
    const newTask = {
      id: generateUniqueId(),
      title: noteTitle,
      description: noteDesc,
      tag: selectedTag,
      tagColor: selectedTagColor,
    };
    notes.push(newTask);

    // Save tasks to local storage

    // Clear the input fields
    titleTag.value = "";
    descTag.value = "";

    // Close the popup
    closeIcon.click();
  } else {
    alert("Please select a tag and fill in the title or description.");
  }
});


// Add a dragover event listener to all Kanban columns
kanbanColumns.forEach((column) => {
  column.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    column.classList.add("hover");
  });

  column.addEventListener("dragleave", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    column.classList.remove("hover");
  });
});

// Add a drop event listener to all Kanban columns
kanbanColumns.forEach((column) => {
  column.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {

    if (draggedCard) {
      // Move the card to the new column
      column.querySelector(".kanban-cards").appendChild(draggedCard);

      // Update the card's status
      const newStatus = column.querySelector("h5").textContent.trim();
      const cardId = draggedCard.getAttribute("data-id");
      const updatedTask = notes.find((task) => task.id === cardId);
      if (updatedTask) {
        updatedTask.tag = newStatus;
        // Update the task's status in your data storage
      }

      // Reset the draggedCard variable
      draggedCard = null;
    }
  });
});

// Generate a unique ID for each card
function generateUniqueId() {
  return Date.now().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
}

// Event listener for radio buttons to update the selected tag
const tagRadioButtons = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="radio"]');

tagRadioButtons.forEach((radio) => {
  radio.addEventListener("click", () => {
    selectedTag = radio.nextElementSibling.textContent.trim();
    selectedTagColor = tagColors[selectedTag];
  });
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;400;500;600&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  background: #f8f0ff;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.sidebar {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 240px;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0 1.7rem;
  color: white;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  background: white;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.sidebar:hover {
  width: 240px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu {
  height: 88%;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  bottom: 1rem;
  padding-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

.menu li {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.logo {
  height: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-left: 3px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  color: #69665C;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.logoimg {
  width: 42px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.logo h2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.dash:hover,
.dash {
  background-color: #FFF9DE;
}

.personal:hover,
#personal:active {
  background-color: #D2CEFF;
}

.work:hover,
.work:active {
  background-color: #D1E5F7;
}

.school:hover,
.school:active {
  background-color: #FFCECE;
}

.coding:hover,
.coding:active {
  background-color: #DAF2D6;
}

.logout:hover {
  background-color: gray;
}

.logout:hover span {
  color: white;
}

.menu a {
  color: #69665C;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1.5rem;
}

.menu a span {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.menu a i {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.fas.fa-user {
  color: #FFB843;
}

.fas.fa-clipboard {
  color: #7875A9;
}

.fas.fa-folder-open {
  color: #7DA9D6;
}

.fas.fa-book {
  color: #FF8E8E;
}

.fas.fa-laptop-code {
  color: #7BC683;
}

.fa-solid.fa-arrow-right-from-bracket {
  color: red;
}

.logout {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}


/* MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */


/* MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */


/* MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */

.main {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem;
  color: #69665C;
}

.header-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px 2rem;
}

.header-wrapper img {
  max-width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* /////MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */


/* MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */


/* MAIN YUNG SA RIGHT */


/*yung notes*/


/* Add this CSS for the to-do cards */

.todo-card {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.todo-card-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  max-width: 280px;
}

.todo-card-footer {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.todo-card-header h3 {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 260px;
}

.delete-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: red;
}

.fas.fa-trash {
  color: red;
}

.todo-text {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  resize: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/* POP UP PAG INADD */

.popup-box {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  z-index: 999;
  color: #69665C;
}

.popup-box .popup {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 1000;
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  justify-content: center;
}

.popup-box,
.popup-box .popup {
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.25s ease;
}

.popup-box.show,
.popup-box.show .popup {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.popup .content {
  background: lavender;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: calc(100% - 50px);
}

.popup .content header {
  padding: 15px 25px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #69665C;
}

.content header p {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.content header i {
  color: #69665C;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 23px;
}

.content header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.content form {
  margin: 15px 25px 20px;
}

.content form .row {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

form .row label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.content form :where(input,
textarea,
select) {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: 0px 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.content form textarea {
  height: 150px;
  resize: none;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}

.content form button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  background: #5D5A8C;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.popup {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* ADD TASK */

.addBox {
  margin: 1rem 0;
  background: #7875A9;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .5rem;
  border-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.addBox:hover {
  background: #5D5A8C;
}

.addBox:active {
  transform: scale(1.01);
}

.add i {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.add p {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}


/* ADD TASK TAPOS */


/* tags */

.btn-radio {
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn-radio input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.btn-radio input[type="radio"]+label span {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.btn-radio input[type="radio"]:checked+label span {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.btn-radio i {
  padding-right: 5px;
}


/* Kanban Board */

.kanban-board {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.kanban-column {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.kanban-column h5 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0 0 10px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #69665C;
  color: #69665C;
}

.kanban-cards {
  min-height: 500px;
  /* Adjust the minimum height as needed */
}


/* Kanban Card */

.kanban-card {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.kanban-card h4 {
  font-size: .9rem;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.kanban-card p {
  font-size: .8rem;
  margin: 0;
}

.kanban-card-tag {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  color: white;
  font-size: .8rem;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


/* Define different styles for different card tags */

.kanban-card.tag-Personal {
  border-left: 3px solid #7875A9;
}

.kanban-card.tag-Work {
  border-left: 3px solid #7DA9D6;
}

.kanban-card.tag-School {
  border-left: 3px solid #FF8E8E;
}

.kanban-card.tag-Coding {
  border-left: 3px solid #7BC683;
}


/* Card Dragging Styles */

.kanban-card.is-dragging {
  opacity: 0.5;
}


/* Card Placeholder Styles */

.kanban-card-placeholder {
  background-color: #ddd;
  height: 150px;
  /* Adjust the height as needed */
  border: 1px dashed #333;
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Font Awesome Cdn Link -->
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/04558dcba4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- POP UP PAG DRINAG -->
<div class="popup-box">
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="content">
      <header>
        <p>New Task</p>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>
      </header>
      <form action="#">
        <div class="row title">
          <label for="title">Title</label>
          <input id="title" placeholder="Enter your to-do here">
        </div>
        <div class="row description">
          <label for="desc">Description</label>
          <textarea id="desc" placeholder="Provide additional details..."></textarea>
        </div>



        <div class="row dropdown">
          <label>Tags</label>

          <div class="btn-radio" id="radio">
            <input type="radio" id="radio01" name="radio" />
            <label for="radio01"><span><i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i>Personal</span></label>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-radio">
            <input type="radio" id="radio02" name="radio" />
            <label for="radio02"><span><i class="fas fa-folder-open"></i>Work</span></label>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-radio">
            <input type="radio" id="radio03" name="radio" />
            <label for="radio03"><span><i class="fas fa-book"></i>School</span></label>
          </div>
          <div class="btn-radio">
            <input type="radio" id="radio04" name="radio" />
            <label for="radio04"><span><i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>Coding</span></label>
          </div>

        </div>
        <button>Add Task</button>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- DONE DRAG -->




<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="logo">
    <h2><img src="doit.png" class="logoimg"><span>DoIt!</span></h2>
  </div>

  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="dash">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
        <span>Home</span>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="personal" id="personal" draggable="true">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-clipboard"></i>
        <span>Personal</span>
      </a>
    </li>

    <li class="work">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-folder-open"></i>
        <span>Work</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="school">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-book"></i>
        <span>School</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="coding">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
        <span>Coding</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="logout">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right-from-bracket"></i>
        <span>Log out</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- main sa right -->
<div class="main">
  <div class="header-wrapper">
    <div class="header-title">
      <h2>Home</h2>
    </div>
    <img src="rimuru.jpg" alt="">
  </div>

  <!-- BUTTON PARA SA ADD -->
  <div class="addBox">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
    <p>Add Task</p>
  </div>

  <div class="kanban-board">
    <!-- To Do Column -->
    <div class="kanban-column">
      <h5>To do</h5>

      <div class="kanban-cards" id="todo-cards"></div>

    </div>

    <!-- In Progress Column -->
    <div class="kanban-column in-progress">
      <h5>In progress</h5>
      <div class="kanban-cards" id="inprogress-cards"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Completed Column -->
    <div class="kanban-column">
      <h5>Completed</h5>
      <div class="kanban-cards" id="completed-cards"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```